# Apache Camel excluded folders, but it still polling

Tags: java

I have a application running with Apache Camel ftp component, we have route configuration like below:

```
sftp.server=sftp:user@host:12345/?antExclude=dirExcluded&noop=true
```

and in directory [dirExcluded], there're many sub-directories, and files.

I want camel to skip polling sub directories of excluded folders so it can save a lot of polling. Looking into the source code of camel-ftp, looks like there's no way to do that.
Can anyone have some suggestions please?

Edit: antInclude -> antExclude  per Markoto's comment

Comment: If you want to *exclude* those directories, why are you using `antInclude`?

Comment: sorry I meant antExclude